# Match with sed between 2 different patterns

Tags: linux, sed

I want to catch the output between 2 different patterns, for example :

```
sed -n '/^pattern1/,/^pattern2/p;/^pattern2/q'
```

But I want to catch the output without the patterns in cause.

I know that `grep -Ev` will help me, but I wonder how it's done with sed.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "without the patterns in cause" bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `awk`:

```
awk '/^pattern1/{p=1;next}/^pattern2/{p=0}p' file
```

The variable `p` is set when the pattern `pattern1` is found, and the variable is reset when the second pattern is met.

The `p` at the end of the script will trigger the default awk action, i.e. print the line if `p==1`.